# INDEX/MATCH to return matched value in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been having an issue trying to get Excel to return the value in a cell that is immediately to the right of the matched value in a table. I have been trying to use the following formula, but it doesn't appear to like tables, and can't seem to work out how to reference a cell relative to the matched cell (not just a single column reference).

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($K$18:$L$42,SMALL(IF($K$18:$K$42=$B$2,ROW($K$18:$K$42)-17),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($K$18:$L$42,SMALL(IF($K$18:$K$42=$B$2,ROW($K$18:$K$42)-17),ROW(1:1)),2))}
```

Appreciate any help/guidance on this!

Comment: Break the formula down onto its parts and see where the error is coming.  First does `SMALL(IF($K$18:$K$42=$B$2,ROW($K$18:$K$42)-17),ROW(1:1))` return the correct relative row reference?  If it does then do the INDEX then the ISERROR.  also as a note if you are using 2007 or later look into IFERROR instead as it will shorten your formula.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be important to know the names of the columns (and table name if external to the table) if you are asking how to convert xlA! range references to a table's columns?

Answer (score 1):

In the following sample image, the formula in I7 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[fld B], 
         AGGREGATE(15, 7, (ROW(Table1[fld A])-ROW(Table1[#Headers]))/(Table1[fld A]=H7), COUNTIF(H$7:H7,H7))), 
         TEXT(,))
```

[image: aggregate_table]